# Does slurm require same version accross all nodes?

Tags: slurm

I'me experimenting with a cluster set-up, where different nodes have either 19 or 20 version of slurm.
The managing node has SLURM 20.

For some reason, nodes with SLURM 19 can't ping the manager (`scontrol ping` returns `Slurmctld(primary) on node0 is DOWN`).

I wonder if it is the incompatibility of SLURM 19/20 or did I messed-up anywhere else.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have different versions of the slurm components on your system, but there is an order:

slurmdbd >= slurmctld >= slurmd >= slurm-commands

And you should stay withing three releases (see https://slurm.schedmd.com/SLUG20/Field_Notes.pdf, slide 14).

As a side node: The major releases are the first four digits, based on year and month (yy.mm): 20.02 is the current major release 19.05 is the previous, and 20.11 is the next.

Comment: OK, that, probably, I messed-up somewhere else.